# Do magical fields of study need their own names?

Tags: magic, names

I have a magic system which is based on the senses. As it stands each sense magic has its own name but my beta reader of the first draft has found the names confusing (the names are pretty terrible). Does each sense magic need its own name, or would it work saying the character used pain magic to do x,y and z? I'm concerned about having to repeat the word magic an awful lot with the second option.

Comment: This isn't a question about world building so much as writing style. Perhaps it would be more appropriate on [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks, should I post it again on there?

Comment: A moderator should be able to move it. Unfortunately, I borked my flagging capability, so if someone else could hit it with the appropriate flag, it will be more likely for a moderator to pick it up.

Comment: You could rephrase this question along the lines of "Given a magic system based on the five senses, what would the fields of study/types of magic be called in a way that emulates the physical sciences?" (if I'm understanding what you're getting at, that is.)

Comment: @Azuaron I've raised a flag for the mods to move it. In the meantime, I've also voted to close this as off-topic for our site, for the reason you identified.

Comment: you can also use different words for magic, like we have different words for say, spoke yelled whispered,  enchanted channeled evoked

Comment: Hello and welcome!  I saw the flags and was preparing to migrate this to Writers, but I see it's got several answers here and that you've accepted one.  So I'll leave it here and on hold for now.  If you still have a question (beyond what's here), feel free to directly ask it on Writers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they need names but I don't think names are bad either. I would suggest that if you have tons of different magic fields which are being used names may get confusing. On the other hand, if you have only a few magic fields that are being used names may be helpful. I would say that if more than 10 magic fields are used or if a magic field is only used once or twice it isn't worth naming.If there are only 3 or 4 magic fields or the field is used in most chapters then name it. These are guidelines not rules though.

Comment: It's 6 different fields, but one of them is barely mentioned as it's almost useless so it's effectively 5 fields. Would that be heading towards too many names?

Comment: 5 is probably ok for the vast majority of readers. Some people might complain that it is confusing but most won't.

Answer (score 1):

The "repeat the word magic" problem can be solved based on the approach you want to take to your history or based on what fits the most in your writing style. Since I don't think there is a right answer to the question because it is up to you how to create your world here I listed some ideas:

- Describe the essence of the spell: if you want to use a hearing increasing spell, you can describe how his hearing evolves.
- I don't think that is the case, but you can use the words relative to the casting type like: enchantment, rituals, spells, incantation or charm.
- In dialog cases, a nice approach would be to create a spell like (note this quote is more like a ritual approach, but you can develop such for spells):

  > "I give you a claw I ripped from a rat, I give you the name and the name is lost, I give you the blood from out of my vein..." -Neil Gaiman, Sandman Overture
- Use names for some most used spells in combination with other of these ideas listed here and some of your own, note that names have a history and such history would help understand and fix the idea in the readers mind.

I would just like to add that English is not my main language and I can not tell how these ideas might be viewed in the linguistics aspect.

Comment: "It depends" isn't really a useful answer, is it?

Comment: @rek It does depend though.

Comment: Well I can't give a concrete answer if I don't know the whole architecture of his idea.

Comment: Then ask for clarification in a comment. Isn't that how it works here?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment in questions. Isn't that how it works?

Comment: @Skal In general if you need more information you ask for it in a comment.

Comment: @Skal What sort of clarification do you need? I tried not to go into too much detail in the question because I didn't think it was required. I'm happy to provide extra information

Comment: @Bellerephon Thanks, I would have posted a comment, but I just started on this forum and I do not have such permission.

Comment: It's fine, most people, me included, start out like that. On the plus side you have gained 10 rep already.

Comment: @S.Horgan You said you want to avoid repeating the word magic, so you created names for it, right? So, does the casters need to do some sort of action to cast a certain spell, or just say its name? Does they need some sort of tool? Does the study of the magic goes through a system of scholarly for each sense? Are those senses magic available for every caster or, for exemple, if I am a touch caster I can't cast sight?

Comment: @skal it's like an extension of their natural senses, so, for example they can heighten their hearing by using magic specifically related to hearing or if they need to see through an illusion they use their innate "sight magic" to dispell the illusion. Yes, you do need to possess the ability to use a senses magic, so some people might only be able to use hearing based and sight based magic

Comment: Check my edited answer to see if that is kind of what you looking for

Comment: @Skal This is definitely more along the lines of what i was asking and helps with the problem. Thanks for spending your time on this for me

Comment: @S.Horgan Glad to help!

Comment: And just a small idea not related to the question, you might want to take a look in some extrasensory perception papers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea  use alternative names for magic that your reader is already familiar with

Sight magic: can be called sorcery

Touch magic: can be called witchcraft

Hearing magic: Wizardry

Smell magic: the arcane

These names and similar names for Magic are different enough that they won't become repetitive and familiar enough but they won't distract the reader.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it harder for the reader to recognize the terminology? Not only do they have to associate the new words with the type of magic, but they have to disassociate the term from their previous understanding.

Comment: @Dave I see no reason for them to disassociate it from its original meaning, to most of your readers these words have no meaning other than another way different ways of saying magic user.

Comment: Exactly, they currently mean "magic as a whole" but it would be used to refer to a specific magic, I think this would be more confusing to a reader.

Comment: @Dave not really I've read a lot of books and this exact thing is done and I understand perfectly.

Comment: Just because you don't mind doesn't mean nobody would.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid overusing the word magic by naming spells intuitively.

Rather than stating "used pain magic to hurt the person"

You could use "cast a torture spell" or a dozen variants.

Focusing on the spell itself can be more succinct because you may not need to explain the affect. A reader would assume a "torture spell" is something that is unpleasant for the recipient. It also focuses more on what the characters are observing (someone in pain) rather than the intricacies of the magic behind it.

A clever reader would likely be able to determine which magical field a spell fits into, but perhaps not all characters would. This also gives you space for some spells that might be ambiguous as to which field they fit into, or even misleading (directing a small amount of pain in the eye could cause people to confuse it with sight magic?). This could be of particular interest if mages generally fit into a single field.

---

Another option is to name the magic fields with a hint as to what they refer to. For example:

"pain magic"    ->   "palimy"

"sight magic"   ->   "salimy"

"noise magic"   ->   "nalimy"

etc. (these aren't the best names, but you get the idea)

A naming convention can help (the "alimy" after the first letter), or keeping more of the word in the name (like "painost" for pain magic).

Comment: I originally tried a naming convention, but it wasn't very good, hence my attempts to find an alternative. The society is tightly structured on how many fields of Magic a person can use, with more fields giving you more power in society so I can't get away with being ambiguous in that respect, they have to be well defined.

Comment: @S.Horgan the ambiguity could be useful to individuals trying to gain respect by making it seem they can use another type. Someone trying to reach beyond their means.